# Displaying data from 3 different list in one table in jsp/jstl

Tags: java, mysql, list, jsp, jstl

I have three lists. Employee , skillsets , EmployeeSkillsetsRating.

I wish to print a table as below, where the blank spaces will have their rating in that skillset.

```
            EmployeeName1   EmployeeName2   EmployeeName3
```

Skillset1
Skillset2
Skillset3
Skillset4
Skillset5

Now i am able to print all the Employee names as first row successfully using 'Employee' list.
Also I am able to print all Skillsets as first column successfully using 'Skillset' list. 
Following is the working code

```
        <table border="1">

        <th>Activities</th>
        <c:forEach var="employee" items="${listEmployee}">
            <th>
                <td>${employee.name}</td>
            </th>
        </c:forEach>
        <c:forEach var="activity" items="${listActivity}" >
            <tr>
                <td>${activity.activityDetails}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
```

Now the rating for employees is coming from Rating List which also contain EmployeeID from EmployeeList and SkillsetID from Skillset List. How do I print rating in the table by matching both employee name and skillset.

Comment: what is your expected output? is it {employee_name<space>employe's_skill<Space>rating } separated by new line ?

Comment: no. The expected output is the table shown in question. where the columns are employee name and the rows are skillset and respective rating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
    <th>Activities</th>
    <c:forEach var="employee" items="${listEmployee}">
        <th>
            <td>${employee.name}</td>
        </th>
    </c:forEach>
    <c:forEach var="activity" items="${listActivity}" >
        <tr>
            <td>${activity.activityDetails}</td>
           <c:forEach var="employee" items="${listEmployee}">
              <c:forEach var="rating" items="${listRating}">
                 <c:if test = "${rating.employee==employee.ratingDetails && rating.activity==activity.activityDetails)">
                      <td>${rating.ratingDetails}</td>
               </c:if>

              </c:forEach>
           </c:forEach>

        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

For every `activity` you loop through each `employee` and if you find `rating` for that employee and activity in the `ratings` list -you print it as a column value.

There must a rating for every employee in the ratings list.

Comment: That helped. Thank you.